# Помогите решить проблему с imperavi в yii2

Tags: yii2, yii

Пользуюсь редактором imperavi на yii2 basic, администратор находится в модуле. На локалке все работает нормально, но на сервере предприятия, на который загрузил сайт, стоит php 5.6 коммон и менять его они не хотят, т.к. там свои внутренние особенности. Проблема в том, что при загрузке картинки через окно редактора, картинка не загружается в папку и дебуггер выдает ошибку

```
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "default/images-get".' in /home/fks/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:537
```

Подозрения на неправильный роут, но решения найти не могу. Вот мой код, все как описано в описании https://github.com/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget . Адрес localhost:8080 я сменил на реальный домен.

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\admin\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

/**
 * Default controller for the `admin` module
*/
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Renders the index view for the module
 * @return string
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    return $this->render('index');
}

// DefaultController.php
public function actions()
{
return [
    'image-upload' => [
        'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\UploadFileAction',
        'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/uploads/img/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
        'path' => '@app/web/uploads/img', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
    ],
    'images-get' => [
        'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\GetImagesAction',
        'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/uploads/img/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
        'path' => '@app/web/uploads/img', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
        'options' => ['only' => ['*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.JPG', '*.JPEG', '*.png', '*.PNG', '*.gif', '*.ico']], // These options are by default.
    ],
    'file-delete' => [
       'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\DeleteFileAction',
       'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/uploads/img/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
      'path' => '@app/web/uploads/img', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
   ],
    'file-upload' => [
       'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\UploadFileAction',
       'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/uploads/files/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
       'path' => '@app/web/uploads/files', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
       'uploadOnlyImage' => false, // For any kind of files uploading.
       'unique' => false,
       'replace' => true, // By default it throw an excepiton instead.
       'translit' => true,
   ],
    'files-get' => [
       'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\GetFilesAction',
       'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/uploads/files/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
       'path' => '@app/web/uploads/files', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
       'options' => ['only' => ['*.pdf', '*.pptx', '*.zip', '*.doc', '*.docx', '*.xls', '*.xlsx', '*.txt', '*.md']], // These options are by default.
   ],
];
}
```

}

Какая-то проблема с ajax, но как решить не знаю, прошу подсказать.

Answer (score 0):

`'url' => 'http://localhost:8080/uploads/img/'`
Не смущает абсолютный адрес (даже, если сменил)? А вообще так не надо делать. Если хост изменится или порт?
В конфиг надо добавить модуль, либо настроить urlManager.

Comment: Согласен, надо алиас прописать, пытался, но почему-то только так у меня на локалке работало. Попробую неабсолютный адрес.

Comment: Мне кажется тут дело не в том, что он папку для загрузки не может найти, а в неправильном url для get-запроса. Получаю ошибку  404 для GET http://fks.kbsu.ru/default/images-get?_=1562588492660 at 2019-07-08 02:14:15 pm by 85.172.174.14 из которой видно, что по указанному url не может найти, для post-запроса все нормально, возвращается ответ 200 и он таков POST http://fks.kbsu.ru/admin/default/image-upload

Comment: Странно то, что оба экшена images-get и image-apload находятся в одном контроллере default , но для второго в url присутствует параметр admin, возможно в этом дело, но как его настроить и где...?

Comment: Надо файлы экшнов сравнить, туда же параметры приходят. Если что, можно написать свой и унаследовать от вендора.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что на сервере папка была не web, а public_html. Исправил и все заработало.